# Entity Framework losing bits on save

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I create a new person, add it to the list in Entity Framework, and get an error message saying the `PersonID` is missing. I set `PersonID` when I create the object, but it seems to somehow disappear before saving.

Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult EditDetails([Bind(Include = "ProjectID,SDTContactID")] Project project)
{
    project.SDTContactID = project.SDTContactID.Trim();
    Person sdt = db.People.Where(p => p.PersonID == project.SDTContactID).FirstOrDefault();

    if (sdt == null)
    {
        // make a new one
        sdt = new Person { PersonID = project.SDTContactID, PersonName = project.SDTContactID };
        db.People.Add(sdt);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

        sdt = db.People.Where(p => p.PersonID == project.SDTContactID).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return View("Details", project);
}
```

And here is the error caught when debugging

> ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PersonID', table 'Projects.dbo.People'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated

And here is what the watch on PersonID says in the debugger just before the line `db.SaveChanges();` is executed:

```
sdt.PersonID   |   "test_subject@email.com"
```

Doesn't look null to me!

So where is my PersonID disappearing to?

Comment: Please include the EF mapping for that table/type (`Person`) in your question.

Comment: What is that, and where do I find it?